# When is taxonomy appropriate

Tags: taxonomy-terms

If I, hypothetically, ran a business and kept data on products, part data related to those products, and service procedures for those products would it make sense to fit this into the Drupal taxonomy? Is that the Drupal way?

I'm just getting going on Drupal; I have an existing working php application that I shoved into a module without really making use of Drupal functions, to the extent that I even have a separate database. My app uses some non-trivial database organizations, lots of database views and heavy usage of inner joins. This app will be a suite of apps that will also include standard web functions, which I why I want to use Drupal/CMS. But I don't know if I should my module data into taxonomies.

Edit: 99% sure that entities will do what I need, searching on that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomies are best used to define properties that:

1. are shared across multiple content items;
2. need to be grouped with similar properties.

For instance, if you're selling t-shirts, the taxonomy terms 'blue', 'red' and 'yellow' are grouped in the 'color' vocabulary. By tagging all t-shirts of the same color with the same taxonomy term, you define a relationship between those t-shirts. This makes it very easy to generate a page showing all blue, red or yellow t-shirts.

Taxonomy terms, like many other entity types, are 'fieldable', which means that you can add fields to them to contain data. For instance, if you add an image field to the taxonomy terms in the 'color' vocabulary, you could define an example image for each color term.

If this example with t-shirts and colors matches your use case, then the answer to your question is: Yes, taxonomy is the Drupal way to do it.

By the way, the word "entity" has a very broad meaning in Drupal. 'Taxonomy term' is a type of entity, just like 'node', 'user' and 'file'. Saying that "entities will do what you need" is like saying "building materials will allow me to build a house". It's a statement that (almost) can't be wrong. You need to answer the question: Which type of entity is best to solve this specific problem?

Comment: certainly seems like taxonomies are pretty powerful but don't seem to go far as I need. I suppose what I mean by entities is custom entities. My data has multiple linked lists which I think according to http://youtu.be/bB5nK1wp-uA is a sign of going the custom road. I've been experimenting with this https://drupal.org/project/model experimental module, looks very promising.

Comment: I don't know your exact situation, so I can't say if taxonomy is indeed insufficient for your needs. That said, a custom entity type may provide the flexibility you need and Model seems like a good way to get started. If you're looking for ways to relate different pieces of data, you may also want to check out [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation), allows you to define different types of relations between entities. Since those relations are entities themselves, you can even add fields to them. It's really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies in drupal are used to organize and relate content. The Taxonomy module offers the ability to add Vocabularies and then to each vocabulary we can add terms by going to Structure->Taxonomy->Add Vocabulary->Add Term.

Example: If we've a book store then we can organize content by creating vocabularies like, Author, Publisher, Format like ebook, hard copy etc. I'd advise you to study the already available material available on the internet starting from this one.

http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy[Taxonomies](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy)